# php oci8 - how set oracle timestamp returned format

Tags: php, oracle

I am retrieving data from an Oracle database in a php5 script.
I wish to have a specific timestamp format returned.
I found answers on SO that say that a statement similar to the one in Oracle itself will do the trick:

```
$stid = oci_parse ($connection, "alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3'");
oci_execute ($stid);
```

which should ensure that subsequent queries like

```
$stid = oci_parse ($connection, 'select * from table');
oci_execute ($stid);
```

result in timestamp formats being returned in the correct format.

But whatever I do, I always get formats like

```
28-NOV-12 05:37:24.000000 PM
```

So my question is: what's wrong? What statement to execute in php to ensure retrieving the wanted timestamp formats?

Side-question: how can I make sure that php retrieves the timestamp in ISO 8601 format, hence strings like *2012-11-28T17:37:24.000Z* ?

And how to ensure 'Z' in that case, hence not strings like *2012-11-28T16:37:24.000+01:00* ?

Comment: Are you running the subsequent queries on the same `$connection`?

Comment: yes scusi I made a typo: $conn and $connection - should be same connection each time - I corrected the question.

Comment: Hm, try removing the `.ff3` from the format, `DATE` does not have fractional seconds so I'm unsure if that format works.

Comment: Ah I see the format I used should be applied to nls_timestamp_format? I will give them both a try!.... Yes you're correct silly mistake it now works. So let's redirect attention to the ISO 8601 part of the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ff3` is not valid for the `DATE` datatype, since it does not contain fractional seconds.

As to your ISO8601 formatting, only `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` has an actual time zone. If you want that formatted with a Z (ie UTC), you can do;

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'UTC';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"';
```

Then when you select a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, you'll get it in that format.

If you need to format `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` like that, you can just fake the time zone part by using the formats;

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss".000Z"'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
```

[SQLfiddle for testing here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4aed/5).

Answer (score 1):

Use Function:  TO_CHAR

Example:  to_char(<>,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FF3"Z"')

Docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129

Format Models:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34510